# rsync shell script with input

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, rsync

I would like to have a rsync shell script that the user will enter the folder or file to sync to another server.

i.e. - `./deploy /html/` or `./deploy /html/kuky.txt`

the script will wait for the input and then will execute the rsync script
please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
echo "Enter file or folder path"

read target

if [ ! -e "$target" ]
then
    echo $target does not exist
else
    echo Transferring $target
    rsync -avzr $target user@example.com:/home/user/target_directory
fi
```

put this into a file called sender.sh. Then call
    bash sender.sh
from command line.

I suggest you look up options of rsync command. They may change behavior a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

Can's answer requires a user to run the script and then type the path manually, the following will allow you to use the syntax you specified in your OP:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Transferring ${*} to server... "
rsync -az ${*} <user>@<server>:/path/to/target/ 1> /dev/null
echo "Done!"
```

This script will take **all** CLI arguments given to it as source directories/files, and send them to the server.